# Validation for wpf without MVVM patern

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, silverlight

I am using WPF and binding the DataContext using code behind file. I am not following MVVM or any other pattern. I want to add validation to my form. I used data **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations** for validation. Below is the code file

```
[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Person : PropertyValidateModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Score { get; set; }
}


[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]
public abstract class PropertyValidateModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    // check for general model error    
    public string Error { get { return null; } }

    // check for property errors    
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

            if (Validator.TryValidateProperty(
                    GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(this)
                    , new ValidationContext(this)
                    {
                        MemberName = columnName
                    }
                    , validationResults))
                return null;

            return validationResults.First().ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

My XAML file is as below:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFDataContext.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=Score, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        <Button Name="btnSave" Click="btnSave_Click" Content="Save" ></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This add validation to the form but if i want to check if model is valid or not then how i can check? Please help me out as i am not getting IsValid property which i used in MVC pattern for ModelState.IsValid. Please help.

Comment: Why not use MVVM? You're having to work pretty hard to get around it.

Comment: I do not have basic knowledge of MVVM and my project is not built in MVVM pattern so please help me out for this.

Comment: Can you use WinForms instead of WPF?

Comment: No. I Can't use winform.

Comment: `wpf without MVVM patern` - There's no such thing. Forget it. That said, you're using DataBinding here, and IDataErrorInfo, that IS MVVM in my book.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lostfocus event of TextBox ,for example you want email validation of texbox

Your XAML

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtEmail1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" MaxLength="70"  Margin="0,5,5,0" Style="{StaticResource  md-3s-textbox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  LostFocus="TxtEmail1_LostFocus"  >
```

Your Code Behind

```
 public static bool IsValidEmail( string email)
        {
            string pattern = @"^(?!\.)(""([^""\r\\]|\\[""\r\\])*""|" + @"([-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]|(?<!\.)\.)*)(?<!\.)" + @"@[a-z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-z0-9]\.[a-z][a-z\.]*[a-z]$";
            var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return regex.IsMatch(email);
        }

    private void TxtEmail1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValidEmail(txtEmail1.Text.ToString().Trim())==false)
        {
            txtEmail1.ToolTip = "Invalid Email";
            txtEmail1.BorderBrush= System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
        }
        
    }
```